# Declaring Explicit interfaces and the does not contain a definition error C#

Tags: c#, class, interface, explicit-implementation

I am having an issue with an explicit interface that I created and am getting the exception,

> 'x' does not contain a definition for 'y' and no extension method 'y' accepting a first argument of type 'x' could be found

I have a series of classes.  The base class:

```
public interface IFactoryResponse
{
    object instance { get; set; }
    string instanceconfig { get; set; }
}
```

The class that explicitly implements it:

```
public class FactoryResponseImpl : IFactoryResponse
{
    object IFactoryResponse.instance {
        get { return ((IFactoryResponse)this).instance; }
        set { ((IFactoryResponse)this).instance = value; }
    }

    string IFactoryResponse.instanceconfig   {
        get { return ((IFactoryResponse)this).instanceconfig; }
        set { ((IFactoryResponse)this).instanceconfig = value; }
    }
}
```

and in another class I get the above error.  Visual studio can find the interface and class ok, but it can't resolve the instance property.  What am I missing here.  I am probably missing one of the more refined rules of explicit inheritance.

```
if (facconfig.useabstract) {
    response.instance = Activator.CreateInstance(m_entassembly.GetType(entconfig.Classname, true, true));
    response.instanceconfig = facconfig.config;
} else {
    Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(facconfig.assemblyfile);
    object Obj = Activator.CreateInstance(assem.GetType(facconfig.Classname, true, true));
    response.instance = Obj;
    response.instanceconfig = facconfig.config;
}
```

Comment: Is the interface defined in the same assembly?

Comment: It is indeed defined in the same assembly

Comment: you need to cast the object as that interface then you can see the properties

Comment: Isn't this a stack overflow exception waiting to happen? `return ((IFactoryResponse)this).instance;`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but looks like your property call itself.

Comment: I haven't really dealt with explicit interface implementation before.  If there is a better way to do it then by all means let me know.

Comment: How can I referrence the instance variable in the base class?

Comment: why do want to set the property as the value you setting it

Comment: The class is an instance of the IFactoryResponse method.  As such it should have its instance and instanceconfig members set.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your implementation is incorrect. It will cause `StackOverflowException` because property calls itself. You can easily implement the properties using autoproperties:

   ```
   public class FactoryResponseImpl : IFactoryResponse
   {
       object IFactoryResponse.instance { get; set; }

       string IFactoryResponse.instanceconfig { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. When interface member is implemented explicitly you have to look at variable as the interface, either by casting your class instance to that interface or assigning it into a variable types as that interface.

   ```
   if (facconfig.useabstract) {
       ((IFactoryResponse)response).instance = Activator.CreateInstance(m_entassembly.GetType(entconfig.Classname, true, true));
       ((IFactoryResponse)response).instanceconfig = facconfig.config;
   } else {
       Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(facconfig.assemblyfile);
       object Obj = Activator.CreateInstance(assem.GetType(facconfig.Classname, true, true));
       ((IFactoryResponse)response).instance = Obj;
       ((IFactoryResponse)response).instanceconfig = facconfig.config;
   }
   ```
3. Why do you need the interface to be implemented explicitly? You shouldn't do that unless you have very good reason. With implicit implementation everything is much easier:

   ```
   public class FactoryResponseImpl : IFactoryResponse
   {
       public object instance { get; set; }

       public string instanceconfig { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And your other code should work just fine.

Comment: This is a very good answer.  Every time I think I know all I need to know I run into a problem like this.  I need to go over this a bit more but I think your answer is the best one.  I am just going to eliminate the explicit interfaces implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Your explicit implementations are referencing themselves. You should be referencing a private field or the public implementation. E.g.:

```
public class FactoryResponseImpl : IFactoryResponse
{
    DatabaseFactoryResponseInstance _instance;

    public FactoryResponseImpl()
    {
        _instance = new DatabaseFactoryResponseInstance();
    }

    object IFactoryResponse.instance {
    get { return (object)_instance; }
    set { 
            if (value != null)
            {
                DatabaseFactoryResponseInstance dbInstance;
                dbInstance = value as DatabaseFactoryResponseInstance;
                if (dbInstance == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                _instance = dbInstance;
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: Where did the DatabaseFactoryResponseInstance come from?

Comment: It is one possible implementation of the `instance`.

Comment: duh,  Silly me.  I thought I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you where aiming for?

```
public interface IFactoryResponse
        {
            object instance { get; set; }
            string instanceconfig { get; set; }
        }

        public class FactoryResponseImpl : IFactoryResponse
        {
            object IFactoryResponse.instance { get; set; }
            string IFactoryResponse.instanceconfig { get; set; }
        }

        class Test
        {
            public void TestMethod()
            {

                IFactoryResponse response = new FactoryResponseImpl();
                response.instance = null;
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If one uses explicit interface implementations like IFactoryResponse.instance, then these methods are not publicly visible. Either you need to cast to IFactoryResponse to access them or define the methods as public: public object instance { ... }.